# Handling numbers with leading zeros in Tcl

Tags: parsing, integer, tcl, octal

I am having trouble in Tcl using numbers with leading zeros.  I am parsing some numbers that can have leading zeros, such as "0012", which should be interpreted as the integer "twelve".

```
$ tclsh
% set a 8 
8
% set b 08
08
% expr $a - 1
7
% expr $b - 1
expected integer but got "08" (looks like invalid octal number)
```

What is the best way to handle numbers that might have a leading zeros in Tcl?

On a side note, what would constitute a valid octal number in Tcl, if "08" is an invalid one?

Comment: actually for your examples you are lucky and get an error message. If the string were 011 you would silently get wrong number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to read [Tcl and Octal Numbers](http://wiki.tcl.tk/498) at the Tcl wiki.  The canonical way is to treat your input as a string and use the [`scan`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/scan.htm) command to extract the numbers.  That leads to this, yes multiline, proc:

```
proc forceInteger { x } {
    set count [scan $x %d%s n rest]
    if { $count <= 0 || ( $count == 2 && ![string is space $rest] ) } {
        return -code error "not an integer: \"$x\""
    }
    return $n
}
```

Comment: Multiline, yes, but the "scan" recommendation is the most compact and easy to understand that I have seen.  "set b [scan b %d]" meets my needs.  The remainder of the forceInteger proc is devoted to defensive input validation.

Answer (score 4):

This is the cleanest solution:

```
% expr [ scan "08" %d ] - 1
7
```

Furthermore:

```
% expr [ scan "09" %d ]
9
% expr [ scan 09 %d ]
9
% set nine 09
09
% expr [ scan $nine %d ]
9
% set success [ scan $nine %d number ]
1
% puts $number
9
```

**scan** : *This is probably what you care about.*  Converts the `"09"` (even as a string) into a decimal number `9`.

> Note: 
>   1. If this value cannot be converted into a decimal value, then `scan` will return an empty string (`{}`).
>   2. If a variable name is provided to the `scan` command (like the `number` variable in the example above), then the return value indicates *status*, `0`: failed to parse decimal, and `1`: success.

**expr** : Used here to demonstrate that `expr` interprets the value as a number, and addresses the original question. It evaluates an expression (e.g. `expr {2*3}` returns `6`).

Comment: If you are working with extremely large numbers, i.e. not dates or times, then use this syntax: ```scan $nine %11d nine```

Answer (score 2):

```
set $clean_number [regsub {^0*(.+)} $troublesome_number {\1}] this doesnt work 
set clean_number "" 
set $troublesome_number 08
% set $clean_number [regsub {^0*(.+)} $troublesome_number {\1}]
wrong # args: should be "regsub ?switches? exp string subSpec varName"
```

an easier solution is:

```
set x 08
regsub {^[0]} $x {\1} x
puts $x
=>8
```

Answer (score 2):

I have all these Tcl/Tk version 8.1 programs that have become broken because Tcl/Tk 8.5.10 is not handling string/numeric conversions correctly.

Here, shell into Tcl, and type:

```
 %  expr {01}
 1
```

(and so on..)

```
 %  expr {06}
 6

 %  expr {07}    
 7
```

and then we get to 8...

```
 %  expr {08}
 missing operator at "_@_"
```

looks like invalid octal number

But it gets worse.  Still in Tcl shell, try this:

In my Tcl8.1 shell:

```
 % format "%.0f" {08}
 8
```

But in my new and improved Tcl8.5 shell, I get an error:

```
 % format "%.0f" {08}
 expected floating-point number but got "08" (looks like invalid octal number)
```

This is just goofy!
I have all this code that works ok in Tcl7.6 and Tcl8.1, but which started giving
weird, random results in Tcl8.5.  Only when the number 08 happened to
get generated or be used!   I have spent hours trying to figure out the problem.
But it turns out it is just a *nasty sack of code* that I am using!

So, I am posting this rant as a warning.
Tcl/Tk Version 8.5.10 handles the number eight incorrectly.  If you are
expecting sane behavior from your format statements, this *will not happen*.
Your code will fly along, until it encounters a string valued at {08}, and
the Tcl 8.5.10 interpreter will generate an error, because it will assume
that {08} is a special-case *octal number*, regardless of the fact that all the
other little numbers you have used will have worked just fine!

One possible solution to the problem mentioned above is to downgrade back to a Tcl 8.1
shell. I have confirmed that that version does at least handle format 
statements for the number 08 correctly.  Tcl 8.5.10 shell simply does not.

Comment: You should use [scan "08" %d] instead of [format "%.0f" "08"]. scan convert the string "08" to number (8). format convert the number "08" to string but "08" is invalid number in tcl so don't use format in such case

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.psg.com/~joem/tcl/faq.html#LeadingZeros) should help you

Valid octal numbers can only contain the digits 0-7 and must start with 0

Comment: That link suggest writing a multiline proc to strip zeros off. I had hoped there might be something simpler.

Comment: Correct on the octal digits. Silly me.  Of course "8" is not a valid octal digit. Internal off by one error...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've always used:

```
set $clean_number [regsub {^0*(.+)} $troublesome_number {\1}]
```

to sanitize `$troublesome_number`s.

Comment: This regsub method is correct but very similar to one of the solutions in the link Mick Sharpe opened with.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/tclsh

#Regsub TCL script to remove the leading zeros from number. 
#Author : Shoeb Masood , Bagalore

puts "Enter the number"
set num [gets stdin]
regsub  {^0*} $num {\1} num
puts $num
```